# How can I Install curl on Linux?

Tags: linux, curl, networking

I am new to networking. And I wanna install curl on my ubuntu 14.04
 Help me with all the packages or any other services needed to install curl

Comment: Use your systems software management system. That is the preferred way to install and remove software from such a system. Far better than a "wild installation" with its huge security problems as it is common on MS-Windows systems for example.

Comment: Did you try `curl --help`? Isn't it already installed?

Comment: how can i know if curl is already installed .?

Comment: And where can I locate the .pid file of curl ?

Answer (score 10):

Simply run this command in the terminal.

`sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: should I need apache to use it?

Comment: Why is this answer down voted? It could use some improvement, but it is basically right.

Comment: @PeeKay Why apache? `cURL` primary is a CLI application. You just use it. If you are talking about some cURL extension of something, for example php's curl extension which can be used inside the apache http server as a module, then things are different. But then you should say so in your question. _Be precise_.

Comment: No i just wanna install curl. Thanks, It works :)

Comment: @arkascha “Answering bad/off-topic posts only encourages more of the same.” (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267504/139746 ) therefore this answer makes the site worse and should be downvoted.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Development tools, their usage and installation are explicitly considered on-topic AFAIK. That is why I consider this question to be on-topic. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install php-curl

Run this command after installing apache server